How do I create a nested vector from one data.table column data grouping by another column?
Given the following data.table:
Col_1 <- c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B")
Col_2 <- c("AA", NA, "AA", NA, "BB", "BBB")
dt <- data.table(Col_1, Col_2)

I need to create a new column with a nested vector with the existing elements in Col_2 for each instance of Col_1, providing a desired output such as:
Col_1    c3
<char> <int>
1:      A     c("AA", NA, "AA")
2:      B     c(NA, "BB", "BBB")

I tried the code below...
dt[, .(c3= sapply(Col_2,c))
   , .(Col_1)]

... which outputs:
    Col_1     c3
   <char> <list>
1:      A     AA
2:      A     NA
3:      A     AA
4:      B     NA
5:      B     BB
6:      B    BBB

How do I get the desired result?

Something like dt[, .(c3 = list(Col_2)), by = Col_1] ?

Solved! Yet, dt[, .(c3 = c(Col_2)), by = Col_1] does not work, I´d like to undeerstand why.   Anyway, thank you

length(c(1:10)) is 10, length(list(1:10)) is 1. As you want to collapse to a single row, you need a length 1 output. col_2 is a vector. c(col_2) is the same as col_2 when col_2 is a vector. identical(1:10, c(1:10)) gives TRUE.

data.table uses lists to form data frames so if you want a list column you need to nest one list in the other.   Since .(...) is a data.table synonym for list(...) we can write: dt[, .(c3 = .(Col_2)), by = Col_1]

You should use nested .() to define it
> dt[, .(c3 = .(Col_2)), by = Col_1]
    Col_1        c3
   <char>    <list>
1:      A  AA,NA,AA
2:      B NA,BB,BBB

or you can use aggregate from base R like below (be aware of na.action = argument)
> aggregate(cbind(c3 = Col_2) ~ Col_1, dt, list, na.action = na.pass)
  Col_1          c3
1     A  AA, NA, AA
2     B NA, BB, BBB

